# Flutter make container height match_parent

Tags: flutter, widget

I have to build the following widget, which will be placed inside a ListView as parent element.

[image: Desgin]

I have a problem with the green rectangle on the left side.
Basically I have structured my widget like that:

```
-> Card
   -> Stack
      -> Container for the "right" side (Tire ID, icon, temperature, pressure info)           
      -> Container for green rectangle,
      -> Container with boxed decoration for green circle
      -> Text with "5LO"
```

But this is how it looks like right now:

[image: no green rectangle]

Basically the Container for the rectangle on the left side **is not stretching it's height to full height of the parent stack**. How can I do this?

Code:

```
class TireListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  static const _circleSize = 36.0;

  const TireListItem({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        key: Key('cardTire'),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
          children: [
            _TireContentInfoWidget(),
            _buildTireIndicationRectangle(), // This should build the rectangle on the left side.
            _buildTirePositionCircle(),
            _buildTirePositionTextView(context)
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildTireIndicationRectangle() {
    return Container(
      width: _marginLeft,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.green,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.horizontal(
              start: Radius.circular(Dimens.cardCornerRadius))),
    );
  }

  Container _buildTirePositionCircle() {
    return Container(
      width: _circleSize,
      height: _circleSize,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColor.green, shape: BoxShape.circle),
    );
  }

  Container _buildTirePositionTextView(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimens.spacingXs),
        child: Text(
          "2RO",
          style:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.apply(color: AppColor.white),
        ));
  }
}
```

If I set a fixed height to the rectangle container, it would basically work out, but I want that the text information area is defining the full height of the widget:

```
 Widget _buildTireIndicationRectangle() {
    return Container(
      width: _marginLeft,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.green,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.horizontal(
              start: Radius.circular(Dimens.cardCornerRadius))),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it fails with an error: `I/flutter (14814):   needs compositing` and `/flutter (14814):   creator: Column ← Padding ← _EffectiveTickerMode ← TickerMode ← Offstage ← Align ← ClipRect ← Column
I/flutter (14814):     ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← AnimatedBuilder ← ⋯
I/flutter (14814):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (14814):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=387.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (14814):   size: MISSING`

Comment: A different type of error: `I/flutter (14814): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter (14814):   BoxConstraints(w=18.0, h=Infinity)
I/flutter (14814): 
I/flutter (14814): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (14814):   SizedBox`
It's really driving me crazy for 2 days right now. I think the culprit is the ListView maybe. :/

Comment: Thanks for your help @pskink. Positioned.fill was a partly success. It was using the full height afterwards, but it was ignoring the width, so my rectangle stretched over the full screen. The solution from 검은곰BlackBear however, was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using IntrinsicHeight class. If you wrapping Stack with InstrinctHeight, Stack's height is fixed by parent's height. Please look IntrinsicHeight document.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        key: Key('cardTire'),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
          children: [
            _TireContentInfoWidget(),
            _buildTireIndicationRectangle(), // This should build the rectangle on the left side.
            _buildTirePositionCircle(),
            _buildTirePositionTextView(context)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart` did the trick!